# Prevent QCompleter's popup from hiding itself on connected QLineEdit's text changes

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to have a QCompleter that's updated with suggestions from a remote api that's being requested on every text change (e.g. like the google search bar).
This is a bit problematic, because the completer hides its popup after text is added to the line edit, and then doesn't show the popup after the model is updated in the slot connected to the reply's finished signal.

The completer not showing after the update can be solved by a call to its `complete` method, but this causes flicker on the popup because of the hiding before a response is received.

I believe the popup is being hidden here https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/util/qcompleter.cpp?h=6.3.1#n1392, but overriding the event filter to show the popup still causes some flicker, and the suggestions disappear until the model is updated in the `update_callback`.

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from __feature__ import snake_case, true_property  # noqa: F401

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.set_central_widget(self.main_widget)
        self.layout_ = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)

        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.layout_.add_widget(self.line_edit)

        self.completer_model = QtCore.QStringListModel(self)
        self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(self.completer_model, self)
        self.line_edit.textEdited.connect(self.update_model)
        self.line_edit.set_completer(self.completer)

    def update_model(self, query: str):
        """Simulate the network requests that calls self.update_callback when finished."""
        QtCore.QTimer.single_shot(0, lambda: self.update_callback(query))
        #self.completer_model.set_string_list([query + "completedtext"])

    def update_callback(self, query):
        self.completer_model.set_string_list([query + "completedtext"])

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Note: the usage of the `snake_case` feature is often discouraged, mostly because it's completely inconsistent with the API and the documentation, but it's also better to avoid it when sharing code with others, like here on StackOverflow; also, since most PySide questions are also valid for PyQt, it makes very annoying to adapt code (which otherwise would be quite straightforward). I, for one (but I know that I'm not alone), strongly hope that they will remove it, sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `setCompleter()` the line edit automatically calls `setCompletionPrefix()` anytime its text is changed. This is done right after the text is updated, so the completer is always updated "too soon" with the previous text, and that can cause flickering.

A possible solution is to always trigger the completer manually, which is achieved by using [`setWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcompleter.html#setWidget) on the completer (instead of `setCompleter()`) and explicitly calling `complete()`.

```py
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.completer.setWidget(self.line_edit)

    # ...

    def update_callback(self, query):
        self.completer_model.setStringList([query + "completedtext"])
        self.completer.complete()
```